# Two columns Flexbox

Tags: html, layout, flexbox

I would like my elements to line up in 2 columns instead of all the elements in one row and I'm not really familiar with flexbox yet, do you have ideas on how to do this?

```
<div class="Grid Grid--gutters Grid--flexCells">
<div class="Grid-cell">
  <div class="Demo">
    Full-height, even when my content doesn't fill the space.
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3jkR2/

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
flex: 50% 0;
```

for your .Grid-cell. Updated fiddle here --> http://jsfiddle.net/3jkR2/5/